# Search text of classes in a specific class hierarchy in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have an abstract class that has hundreds of children, grandchildren, etc. I need to add a snippet to any of those children that mention a string such as

`somethingNaughty.do()`

Is there a way to perform a search like "Find in Path", but restricted to a specific class hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have all these classes in the same package, you can select that package in Project Hierarchy, then press `Ctrl + Shift + F` so that you search only in that package.

If your classes are spread, I don't think Intellij allows that type of search. You can try to go for a regex search, assuming you can find a pattern between the members of the hierarchy.

I suggest digging through Idea's [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/discover-intellij-idea.html) for potential ideas.

---

**Later edit**

It is doable via the [Class Hierarchy predefined scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html?q=scope&s=quick), available when searching via `Ctrl + Shift + F` .

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Unfortunately, the package organization isn't so good. Checkout around online and couldn't find anything. I find it hard to believe I'm the first person to desire this.

Comment: It is indeed strange not to have this feature. I have fiddled around with my IntelliJ and found something that might help you. For reference, I am using IntelliJ 2019.03 Ultimate. When pressing `Ctrl + Shift + F`, you will have an option to select `scope` - `Class Hierarchy` is available in the dropdown. Tried to search about this functionality on their official site, couldn't find anything about it.